# Python: How do I check each value in a row of a csv file against a scalar value?

Tags: python, csv

I have one csv file with 10 columns and 15 rows. I want to check the fraction of values in each row that are more than value of 40 and pass the list of fractions into another csv file. How can I do so?

[image: Click here to view sample of csv table]

I have tried the following code but can't get it. Thanks in advance.

```css
import csv

n, col, count = 0, 0, 0
dsr_list = []

with open('0' + '_pressure_physical_process.csv', 'r') as f1:
    press_val = csv.reader(f1)
    press_val = list(press_val)
    #print (press_val)

for i in press_val:
    for j in range(0, 10):
        if press_val[i] < 40:
            count += 1
    dsr = (10 - count) / 10
    dsr_list.append(dsr)

with open('dsr.csv', 'w') as f2:
    write = csv.writer(f2)
    write.writerow(dsr_list)
```

Comment: `i` is not a list index, it's the list element.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is the list element, not the list index, so use `i` rather than `press_val[i]`.

You need to reset `count` to `0` before processing each row, otherwise you're adding to the count from the previous rows.

There's no need for the inner loop, you can use `sum()` with a generator to get the number of elements that match the condition.

`csv.reader()` will return arrays of strings, you need to convert them to numbers before comparing with `40`.

```
for row in press_val:
    count = sum(float(col) >= 40 for col in row)
    dsr = count / len(row)
    dsr_list.append(dsr)
```

I've inverted the condition so I don't need to subtract `count` from the number of columns.

The entire thing can be written as a single list comprehension. And there's no need to convert the CSV reader to a list first.

```
with open('0' + '_pressure_physical_process.csv', 'r') as f1:
    press_val = csv.reader(f1)
    dsr_list = [sum(float(col) >= 40 for col in row)/len(row) for row in press_val]
```